# Execute a multi-select SQL query using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to execute a multi-select SQL query using Pyodbc, but getting errors either about no results or no scalar variables. Since I need to create SQL variables that are used at different locations in the query, how could I get this to run in pyodbc?

Would this be feasible if I converted my SQL into a stored procedure?

It is not likely that I will be able to create the logic as a stored procedure as I do not have write access to the database.

Is there any possible way to get this type of query to run in python, or does it need to be modified in some way?

```
| ID    | LNAME    | FNAME    | EMAIL   |
| ----- | -------- | -------- | ------- |
| 1     | Smith    | Bob      | s@a.com |
| 2     | Davidson | Mike     | d@a.com |
| 1     | Campbell | Brian    | c@a.com |
```

This is what I tried so far but keep running into errors.

```
q = """
set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
declare @html varchar(MAX)
decalre @dedupedemails varchar(MAX)
decalre @esc_seq int
    
set @esc_seq = 5;

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.##dedupemail', 'U') is not null
drop table ##dedupemail;
    
with sub1 as (
  select p.ID, p.LNAME, p.FNAME, p.EMAIL
  from dbo.person p
),
sub2 as (
  select
    s1.*,
    case when s1.ID = 1
    then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
    end as IS_ADMIN
  from sub1 s1
)
select distinct s2.* into ##dedupemail
from sub2 s2
where s2.IS_ADMIN = 'Yes'
    
set @html = 'abc';
    
select @dedupedemails = ltrim(stuff((
select '; ' + d.email 
from ##dedupemail d
for xml path('')), 1,1,''));
    
select @dedupedemails as EMAIL_LIST, @html as EMAIL_BODY"""
    
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
    cursor = cnxn()
    cursor.execute(q)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    
    del cnxn
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error caught: ", e)
```

The error:

> Error caught: No results. Previous SQL was not a query.

Another error that I get refers to unknown scalars, but it always gives errors.

Comment: Try `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of the SQL batch.

Comment: Side note: this doesn't require such complicated code. There is no need to insert then select, you could just use another CTE. And if you simplify the code down, you will see that you are only selecting the `email`, and only `WHERE ID = 1`

Comment: Consider [**`STRING_AGG`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for SQL Server 2017+.

Comment: `CASE` statement seems unnecessary and thereby the need of `sub2`. So, replace `where s2.IS_ADMIN = 'Yes'` to `where p.ID = 1` in CTE.

Comment: I realize the code sample posted is trivial and does not need the multi selects. but my actual code dynamically creates html based on temp table data which my query needs to generate first. I only have read access and can only create and insert into temp tables.

Comment: `set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;` Don't do this at all unless you REALLY understand the consequences and you REALLY need to use it.

Comment: thinking maybe I have to convert it to stored procedure or generate the html in python instead.

Comment: I still think you can do it without temp tables, but that's a separate question. Did you try `NOCOUNT`?

Comment: thanks for the suggest, will try it first thing in the morning and update. also thanks for the STRING_AGG function, it seems to be able to replace stuff(for xml)